When this catches the exception, it goes throught the try catch infinitely without waiting for user input. Why?
public void readSquare(Scanner scan) {
        boolean run = true;
        for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < square.length; col++) {
                do{
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Enter an integer number");
                        square[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
                        run = false;
                    }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you must enter an integer.");
                    }
                }while(run);
            }
        }
    }

Im in a beginner java class i have no clue how I could fix it. This is for an assignment so i need to use try/catch.

if the user enters something that is not an integer, that something must be consumed (aka read) otherwise it is still there to be read again and again throw the exception
